# How do I get nanosecond resolution with Java on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I can only get microsecond resolution calling System.nanoTime() in Eclipse (Juno and Kepler) on Mac OS 10.8.5. Is there any way to get nanosecond resolution?

```
for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (System.nanoTime() % 1000 != 0) {
        System.out.println("Got one");
    }
}
```

Comment: The JVM will generally give you as much resolution it can -- that is, what the OS gives it. "This method provides nanosecond precision, but not necessarily nanosecond resolution (that is, how frequently the value changes) - no guarantees are made except that the resolution is at least as good as that of currentTimeMillis()."

Answer (score 1):

You will get a more appropriate `System.nanoTime()` on Mac OS X in JDK 8u20 according to [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040140) bug report.

Briefly [mach_absolute_time](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1398/_index.html) is used with a guard (since it's CPU specific) so it can't go backwards (on multi-core systems).

See the actual code implementing this in JDK8 [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u-dev/hotspot/file/8ea4732884cc/src/os/bsd/vm/os_bsd.cpp#l1021).